# Change Text Color, Hyperlink Color, and Image With Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hyperlink

For my assignment, I need to use javascript to change the text color, hyperlink color, and image on this page:
[image]

The idea is that when a user clicks "Romantic", the text "Select Mood...", "Your Vacation Awaits!", and "Vacations, LLC" will change to red (more red than they already are), when a user clicks "Adventure", the text will change to blue, etc. Also, the picture will change, along with the color of the hyperlinks. Unfortunately, our teacher only gave us an html file, and it's pretty terrible - inline styles, no use of CSS, etc. I don't know if he sent us a bad file on purpose or if he just doesn't know what he's doing. Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Castaway Vacations, LLC</title>
<script src="castaway.js"></script>
</head>
<body leftmargin=0 rightmargin=0 bgcolor=#ffcc99 
text=#993300  link=#993300 vlink=#996633>
<br>
<table width=100% border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
<tr>
<td width=95% align="right" bgcolor=#ffffff>
<img src="castaway_logo.jpg">
<br>
<font face=arial>Vacations, LLC</font></td>
<td bgcolor=#ffffff>&nbsp;</td>  
</tr>
</table>
<br><br>
<div align="center">
<table width=600>
<tr>
<td width=300 valign="top">
   <font face=arial size=3><b><i>Select Mood...</i></b></font><br><br>
   <font face=arial>
   <a onClick="change_color();" href="#">Romantic</a><br><br>
   <a onClick="change_color2();" href="#">Adventure</a><br><br>
   <a onClick="change_color3();" href="#">Relaxation</a><br><br>
   <a onClick="change_color4();" href="#">Family</a><br><br><br><br>
   <a href="#">Request A Brochure...</a>
   </font>
</td>
<td align="center"><img id="rom_main.jpg" src="orig_main.jpg">
<br><i>Your Vacation Awaits!
</tr>
</center>
</body>
</html>
</DOCTYPE>
```

And my javascript:

```
function change_color(){
   document.body.style.color = "red";
   document.getElementById("orig_main.jpg").src = "rom_main.jpg";
}

function change_color2(){
   document.body.style.color = "blue";
   document.getElementById("orig_main.jpg").src = "adv_main.jpg";
}

function change_color3(){
   document.body.style.color = "green";
   document.getElementById("orig_main.jpg.jpg").src = "rel_main.jpg";
}

function change_color4(){
   document.body.style.color = "orange";
   document.getElementById("orig_main.jpg").src = "fam_main.jgp";
}
```

As you can see I tried to create four separate functions for when the user clicks on the different links, but nothing is happening. I'm pretty new at javascript and don't really know what I'm doing, so any help or advice is appreciated. Thank you.

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/HappyHands31/9xsgeyno/4/) - demo

Comment: Yes I submitted that question, but haven't been able to get a response after making unsuccessful revisions (even though it's only been 30 minutes).

Comment: Have you attached event listeners to the links to trigger these functions?

Comment: I don't know what that means / how to do it...is that the same thing as an Event handler?

Comment: Your html is severely out of date! All of those attributes are out of date. Tables are no longer used on modern day websites!

Comment: I know - I didn't make this html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be leveraging [event listeners](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp). I just included the color change for demonstration, but add your logic in the *now* firing functions. For simplicity, I added id's to your `<a>` elements of `one`, `two`, etc, but you can [get a handle](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_elements.asp) on these elements various ways. Observe the following...

```
<a id="one" href="#">Romantic</a>
```

---

```
document.getElementById('one').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.body.style.color = 'red';
    [...]
});
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/ssw3ygjo/) - event listener demo

Check out some [addEventListener()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp) resources for more information.

---

**note** - in your current fiddle, framework options => "No wrap in <body>" - will work just fine - but it's not promoting best practice.

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/b4sc99kc/) - your demo with correctly loaded scripts

[JSFiddle framework documentation](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html) - no wrap?

Comment: Edited code, still not working: http://jsfiddle.net/HappyHands31/9xsgeyno/5/
Please check out my updated code here.

Comment: That's because you kind of mixed our examples and tried inserting the event listeners _inside_ unused functions. If you want to keep functions external, you can do so like such in [this updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pscjono4/)

Comment: Never mind, I see the differences between our codes. Thank you!

Comment: Interesting, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the wrong selector.

```
document.getElementById("orig_main.jpg")
```

is going to look for an element in your html with the id of "orig_main.jpg" but that's the src of the images so javascript can't find anything. The id you're trying to target on your html is written as "rom_main.jpg" (which is an awful id). IDs ideally (heh) should describe the element in some way, not the file name.

Comment: I changed id in my html to "orig_main.jpg" but still nothing is happening.

Comment: this doesnt seem to fix the problem, none of the functions are actually firing

Comment: The JSFiddle one won't work because the functions are scoped separately of the html. Try it on the files.

Answer (score 0):

It should be ok:

```js
function change_color() {
  document.body.style.color = "red";
  document.getElementById("rom_main.jpg").src = "rom_main.jpg";
}

function change_color2() {
  document.body.style.color = "blue";
  document.getElementById("rom_main.jpg").src = "adv_main.jpg";
}

function change_color3() {
  document.body.style.color = "green";
  document.getElementById("rom_main.jpg").src = "rel_main.jpg";
}

function change_color4() {
  document.body.style.color = "orange";
  document.getElementById("rom_main.jpg").src = "fam_main.jgp";
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Castaway Vacations, LLC</title>
  <script src="castaway.js"></script>
</head>

<body leftmargin=0 rightmargin=0 bgcolor=#ffcc99 text=#993300 link=#993300 vlink=#996633>
  <br>
  <table width=100% border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
    <tr>
      <td width=95% align="right" bgcolor=#ffffff>
        <img src="castaway_logo.jpg">
        <br>
        <font face=arial>Vacations, LLC</font>
      </td>
      <td bgcolor=#ffffff>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div align="center">
    <table width=600>
      <tr>
        <td width=300 valign="top">
          <font face=arial size=3><b><i>Select Mood...</i></b></font>
          <br>
          <br>
          <font face=arial>
          <a onClick="change_color();" href="#">Romantic</a><br><br>
          <a onClick="change_color2();" href="#">Adventure</a><br><br>
          <a onClick="change_color3();" href="#">Relaxation</a><br><br>
          <a onClick="change_color4();" href="#">Family</a><br><br><br><br>
          <a href="#">Request A Brochure...</a>
          </font>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
          <img id="rom_main.jpg" src="orig_main.jpg">
          <br><i>Your Vacation Awaits!
       </tr>
       </center>
       
          
       
       </body>
       </html>
```